# Getting NullReferenceException in Code

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

What is wrong with this code?

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
 {
        private Dictionary<String , PropertyInfo[]> types;  
        public MainForm()
        {
            //OpenAccountStruct is in the scope
            types.Add("OpenAccount", new OpenAccountStruct().GetType().GetProperties());
        }
}
```

Why am I getting `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Put types = new Dictionary<string, ProeprtyInfo[]>(); on the first line of your method.

Comment: Basic debugging would have taught you that `types` is the null reference here, and so your question has very little, if anything, to do with Reflection.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private Dictionary<String , PropertyInfo[]> types = 
                        new Dictionary<String , PropertyInfo[]>();
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't make an instance of `types` (your Dictionary).

try

```
types = new Dictionary<String , PropertyInfo[]>();
```

Comment: Might wanna mention that `types` is the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The `types` variable is not initialized. 
Use `types = new Dictionary<String , PropertyInfo[]>();`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your types field is not initialized,

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
 {
        private Dictionary<String , PropertyInfo[]> types = new Dictionary<String , PropertyInfo[]>();
        public MainForm()
        {
            //OpenAccountStruct is in the scope
            types.Add("OpenAccount", new OpenAccountStruct().GetType().GetProperties());
        }
}
```